# Is there a language-agnostic way of detecting the user typing a semicolon?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, internationalization

I need an action to happen when the user types a semicolon. What we currently have is

```
if (event.key == 'Semicolon')
```

which works on an English-language keyboard. The problem arises when we try this on a Spanish-language keyboard, where to type a semicolon, the user presses shift+comma. Since it's the Comma key actually being pressed, the value of event.key is 'Comma', which throws a spanner in the works. Is there a language-agnostic way to listen for a semicolon (i.e. picking up both the semicolon-key on the English keyboard, and shift+comma on the Spanish one)?

Comment: I’m not 100% sure as key codes are a bit messy, but the `keydown` and `keyup` events are fired when a physical key on the keyboard is pressed, while `keypress` event (coming right after `keydown`) is bound to the **character** associated with that key, that might change when combined with others. That said, using the `keypress` event associated with the semicolon key code (186 or 187 maybe?) should work

Comment: Turns out I was getting event.key and event.keyCode mixed up. event.key turned out to be what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `beforeinput` event, which will be triggered with a semicolon itself:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinput', (e) => {
  alert(e.data); // ;
});
```